# Xamarin Entry Binding to MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, binding

I am trying to implement everything I can with MVVM rather than code behind, but if I have many objects that I need to access when the entry changes, I don't know how to do it well if at all.

Xaml:

```
<Entry x:Name="UpdatedCost"                       
       TextChanged="UpdatedCost_TextChanged"/>

<Label x:Name="PriceDifLabel"/>

<Entry x:Name="CurrentCost"
       Text="2.5"/>

<Entry x:Name="CurPriceUpdatedCostProfit"
        Text="22%"/>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void UpdatedCost_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out double UpdatedCost))
            {
                double diff = UpdatedCost - double.Parse(CurrentCost.Text);
                string sign = diff > 0 ? "+" : "";
                PriceDifLabel.Text = "(" + sign + string.Format("{0:0.0}", diff) +")";
                PriceDifLabel.TextColor = diff > 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
                PriceDifLabel.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
                CurPriceUpdatedCostProfit.Text = ((int)((double.Parse(CurrentPrice.Text) - UpdatedCost) /
                                                   double.Parse(CurrentPrice.Text) * 100)).ToString() + "%";
            }
            
            
        }
```

I would highly appreciate as detailed help as possible converting this method to MVVM implementation. If it is relevant, my view model is implementing BaseViewModel of [MvvmHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/tree/master/MvvmHelpers).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would create a label for positive and another label for negative differences with your special formattings and content. Then you can bind the IsVisible property to a property in your VM which decides if it's a higher or a lower price.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It looks like "convert this to MVVM" coding request to me. Have you tried creating properties, binding them, changing/rising notification of one property from another property setter, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes I did try it but I am quite a beginner so there were many issues, especially with the fact that it's an entry and that I need its value and other values.

Comment: What's the `CurrentPrice.Text` ? Is it a constant?  And is  `currentcost.text` also a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a model and create different properties for different controls.
I created a simple demo based on your code(take the `PriceDifLabel` 's text and text color for example).

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a model `MyViewModel.cs` and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

And when we change the value of `UpdatedCost`(bind for Entry `UpdatedCost`),we can also change the `PriceDif` accordingly.

MyViewModel.cs

```
   public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        double _updatedCost;
        public double UpdatedCost
        {
            set { 
                SetProperty(ref _updatedCost, value);
                double diff = UpdatedCost - double.Parse(CurrentCost);
                string sign = diff > 0 ? "+" : "";

                PriceDif = "(" + sign + string.Format("{0:0.0}", diff) + ")";

                PriceDifLabelColor = diff > 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------> PriceDif = " + PriceDif);
            }

            get { return _updatedCost; }
        }

        string _currentCost;
        public string CurrentCost
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _currentCost, value); }

            get { return _currentCost; }
        }


        string _priceDif;
        public string PriceDif
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _priceDif, value); }

            get { return _priceDif; }
        }

        Color _priceDifLabelColor = Color.Green;
        public Color PriceDifLabelColor
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _priceDifLabelColor, value); }

            get { return _priceDifLabelColor; }
        }
 
        public MyViewModel() {
            CurrentCost = "2.5";
        }   

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.bind these properties in `page.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:testapp1="clr-namespace:TestApp1"
             x:Class="TestApp1.TestPage2">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <testapp1:MyViewModel></testapp1:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="UpdatedCost" Text="{Binding UpdatedCost}" />

            <Label x:Name="PriceDifLabel" Text="{ Binding PriceDif}" TextColor="{Binding PriceDifLabelColor}"/>

            <Entry x:Name="CurrentCost" Text="2.5"/>

            <Entry x:Name="CurPriceUpdatedCostProfit" Text="22%"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

For more about `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface, you can check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications .

Answer (score 0):

1.Hello, you can create this BaseViewModel and then pass it on to every ViewModel, then you don't always have to create the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for each ViewModel separately.
Then you can inherit it to any ViewModel like here:

```
    using YourApp.ViewModels
    ...
    public class YourViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    ....}
    
    //This is the BaseViewModel:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


    namespace YourApp.ViewModel
    {
    public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    //declares the (required) PropertyChanged event that is defined by 
    //the interface.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // next it is checked if someone has registered for the event,
    // and in this case the event will be raised with the name of the 
    //property being updated.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string 
    propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new 
    PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    // This is a helper method to make setting the property easier. 
    // Right now you can just take this with faith
    // or if you are familiar with generics you can study it a little to 
    // see how it works.
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
       [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
       Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

}
```

}