# Xamarin Forms Entry MVVM Databinding

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to make a Maps Place Search in Xamarin Forms, am following an article ([Google Maps Place Search in Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/05/29/google-maps-place-search-in-xamarin-forms/)) the problem is the listview dosent autorefresh , i must back to previous page(MainPage) and then navigate to SearchPlacePage to get to result.
for that i inspired from this article to create another page and simplify the task.

```
<ContentPage ... >
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <testapp1:MainViewModel ></testapp1:MainViewModel >
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <Entry Text="{Binding PickupText}" />
  <ListView  SelectedItem="{Binding PlaceSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" HasUnevenRows="true" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                      <Label Text="{Binding .}"   />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

and here the MainViewModel :

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string _pickupText;
        public string PickupText
        {
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _pickupText, value);// the problem is the set dosent trigger .. there is no call for SetProperty()..
            }
            get
            {
                return _pickupText;// work fine here 
            }
        }
```

the problem with the MainViewModel  is for each value tapped in the entry , there is no call for the setter ..

i found a solution here , but dosent work for me. [Xamarin Entry Binding to MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68767715/xamarin-entry-binding-to-mvvm)

Comment: I don't believe that `Entry` binding updates on every character typed.  Try `SearchBox` instead

Comment: thanks Jason  for ur quickly answer, look at this article , he is implementing a entry with binding https://www.xamboy.com/2019/05/29/google-maps-place-search-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: have you tried that code?  Does it respond to every character typed, or does it only respond when the "Search" key on the keyboard is tapped?

Comment: yes on every character  typed they call a method GetPlacesByName() and he call api (autocomplete) ... , the problem the list dosent update automatically , on his pictures he showed that the list updated.. but not in my application

Comment: I may have been mistaken in my first comment - it appears that Entry does update its binding on each character

Comment: yes .. but not in my case , i does all the steps ..